# ADX update policy on follower

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, adx

is it possible to have a update policy on a follower cluster in ADX, to write data to a new table in the follower cluster, when data in a leader table is ingested?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, a followed database is in 'read-only' mode - neither metadata nor data can be updated on it, so you can't (for example) - add/remove a table, ingest data into a table.

there's a small set of policies that *can* be overridden on a followed database (e.g. authorization & caching) - those are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/cluster-follower)